# How do I add 'using namespace' to a class definition based on the object name?

Tags: c++, namespaces, software-design

I'm designing a project for school. It will be one that simulates the change in global population by continents.

The first question is one of design. I have a data file that contains constants (rates of change, disasters that occur on that continent, initial populations, etc) for each continent. The data file is organized into a "data" namespace, with each continent having a namespace within data (ie to get Africa's population, use `data::Africa::population`. Is the data file a good idea, or should the rates be set on the object at object creation time? There are about 12 - 15 rates and parameters that need to be set, either using the constructor or functions.

The second question, assuming the data file is a decent idea, is the main question, as per the title. How do I add a "using namespace " to the object so that I can access the variables set in the data file (I don't need to declare them locally in this case. The only variable that would change is the population, the others are constant)?

See below example...

This is the data file, defined in `data.h`:

```
namespace data {
    namespace Africa {
        double population = 12121212;
        // other variables here...
    }
}
```

This is `continent.h` (mostly the constructor):

```
class Continent {
    Continent(string name) {
        if (name == "africa")
            using namespace Africa; // I want this to apply 
                                    // to the entire object, not just the constructor
    }
}
```

I am not worried that the names won't match (ie Africa != africa) because the continents are created automatically inside the `Globe` class. (So first, a globe object is created. Inside the constructor of the globe, the 7 continents are created and added to a continent vector inside `globe.h`. The continents are initialized with a name, the one that I would check and set the 'using namespace' statement).

Is what I'm asking possible to do? If it is, is it a good idea, or are there better practices? I am a novice programmer who is eager to learn, so all help will be appreciated.

Also, the reason I wanted a data file is that the front end of the application (ie the GUI) will not set the rates; the rates are hard coded. I wanted other developers to be able to easily change the rates in one location (or even non-technical people to be able to find a file in which they can change the rates, for example, after a census or something like that).

Comment: In most cases "using namespace ..." Is just a bad idea.

Comment: It is probably better to store the data inside the `Continent` class. Then you can still make a data file, that is opened in `Globe`s constructor, where you read the information for each continent. That way you still have a data file that any non-tech person can open and change if they want.

Comment: @JesperJuhl would defining strings in a namespace be a good use for `using namespace ...`? For example, I have a bunch of strings (ie `earthquake_rate`) that I use throughout the program in different functions.. I could create a namespace `Disaster_Codes` that contains `string er = "earthquake_rate"` and then add `using namespace Disaster_Codes` in the function. In that case, I know what the namespace contains and I know that whenever I test ex. `if (token == er) `, the string will match. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is all kinds of wrong.

`using` statements are processed at compile-time only. You can't use a `using` statement dynamically based on data obtained at runtime (ie, the continent name).

`data.h` is processed at compile-time only, not at runtime. Its values can't be changed dynamically, such as after a census. Changes would require recompiling the project.

I suggest storing all of your values in an external file, database, etc. Then define a `struct` to hold the relevent values and pass that to the `Continent` constructor at runtime.  For each continent, read its pertinent values from the external file/database, fill a struct with them, and construct a `Continent` object with that struct as input. Forget trying to store non-const data in namespaces like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice I've seen a lot of C++ programmers using is putting `using namespace ...` inside a class, function or a command block, so that it does not expand further than you intended to.

Unfortunately, variable namespaces are not allowed as they are handled by the preprocessor.

Also since `using namespace ...` respects scope boundaries.

This will not influence anything that comes after the `if` statement.

```
if (name == "africa")
        using namespace Africa;
```